# Fatal Python error: GC object already tracked

Tags: python, matplotlib, thread-safety

I use matplotlib to create some charts, using the `AGG` backend.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('AGG')
import matplotlib.plot as plt

# ...

def chart_view(request):
    fig = plt.figure
    # Do stuff with fig and finally save it in a Django HttpResponse
    # object and return the HttpResponse object.
```

Now I have a web page that has three images, all three images resulting in running `chart_view`. Only one image usually makes it, and the Django development server stops with "Fatal Python error: GC object already tracked". I'm not certain the problem is in `matplotlib`, it could be in `pandas`.

How can I debug the problem?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found out that it's doing it when I use Debian Jessie's matplotlib 1.4.2 in combination with the latest pandas (0.17.0) that I have installed with `pip install --upgrade --no-deps pandas` (in a virtualenv that uses `--system-site-packages`). If I use Debian's pandas 0.14.1 everything's fine. Go figure why this is. Anyway, using Debian's packages is what I intended to do so this solves the problem for me.