# Why is running a .compute() in dask causing "Fatal Python error: GC object already tracked"

Tags: python, windows, jupyter, dask

I am running Windows 10 with Jupyter notebook version 4.0.6 with Python 2.7.10 and Anaconda 2.4.0 (64-bit)

I am following a blog/tutorial at https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2015/08/14/out-of-core-dataframes-in-python/ :

```
from dask import dataframe as dd
columns = ["name", "amenity", "Longitude", "Latitude"]
data = dd.read_csv("POIWorld.csv", usecols=columns)
with_name = data[data.name.notnull()]
with_amenity = data[data.amenity.notnull()]
is_starbucks = with_name.name.str.contains('[Ss]tarbucks')
is_dunkin = with_name.name.str.contains('[Dd]unkin')
starbucks = with_name[is_starbucks]
dunkin = with_name[is_dunkin]
dd.compute(starbucks.name.count(), dunkin.name.count())
```

This last statement causes an error to come up in my command prompt session running Jupyter as follows:

> Fatal Python error: GC object already tracked

Reading similar questions it could be a possible issue in the source code for dask dealing with Python handling memory, I'm hoping I'm just missing something.

I had a previous issue with headers and dask in this tutorial and had to run:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/blaze/dask.git --upgrade
```

Similar questions that do not help:

[Fatal Python error: GC object already tracked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33480124/fatal-python-error-gc-object-already-tracked)

[Debugging Python Fatal Error: GC Object already Tracked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178606/debugging-python-fatal-error-gc-object-already-tracked)

Comment: Try this with the previous version of Pandas.  I believe that Pandas 0.17.1 introduced some unsafe thread features.

Try `pip install pandas==0.17.0`

Answer (score 2):

Some versions of Pandas do not handle multiple threads well, especially for `pandas.read_csv`.  These are fixed in recent versions of Pandas so this problem can probably be resolved by one of the following:

```
conda install pandas

pip install pandas --upgrade
```